# Root Samsung Galaxy J Max ( SM-T285YD)

Tags: rooting, root-access, samsung, samsung-galaxy-tab

How to root Samsung Galaxy J Max ( SM-T285YD) Tablet and install TWRP Recovery?
Till now i have already tried apps like KingRoot, Towellroot, RootGenius and all of failed rooting this device.

Comment: Rooting and installing TWRP are different things. You'd better start with latter.

Comment: Yeah I know that . I am asking  help for both issues.

Comment: So you should create different questions for each.

Comment: SM-T285YD is Galaxy Tab 2 (2016) ?

Comment: @esQmo Thinking of a similar thing... The T285(Y) model name is tied to Tab A 7.0 (2016), and these 2 devices look markedly similar (J Max does have a gold accent).

Comment: @esQmo No its Galaxy J Max (2016).

Answer (score -1):

If your device is 5.0 and higher you will need to perform oem unlocking. Otherwise you will have a brick

YOUR WARRENTLY IS NOW VOID

Some Samsung devices doesnt work with rooting tools installed on the device so you will need to install KingoRoot/KingRoot.exe on your computer, open it and read instructions..
Rooting your device with kingo root is easier because hardly any setup it required but if you are into SuperSU, kingroot is recommended
Just press that root button and wait.. make sure you have a good amount of battery..

Now installing TWRP. Your device must support TWRP if theres no twrp for your device DO NOT FLASH TWRP THAT WASNT MEANT FOR YOUR DEVICE!!!
Download Samsung Drivers (Your device might install it for you, if not install it from the web)
Download Samsung ODIN v3
Download your twrp recovery in a format of TAR.MD5
Select AP and select your recovery
Put your tab into download mode (Power+VolDown+Home)
Connect it with Usb Cable
Once it said Added! Press START.
Before you do that just make sure F.Reset Time is ticked and reboot also because i dont think ur tab doesnt have a removable battery.

Once it said PASS your done just shut down your tab and boot into recovery (VolUp+Power+Home)
And here you go! You are running TWRP

Also for more help for your device go to this site XDA-DEVELOPERS.COM

Comment: This method won't work on Samsung Galaxy J Max. So far none of the apps available on the internet has able to root this phone both android and pc apps fail. Tried ODIN to but root failed and my phone stucked in downloading updates luckily i had an official firmware and i recovered from it. I think currently rooting is not possible for this phone till developer find it. Don't try to use any unofficial firmware either you can damage your phone i tried every suggestions and methods available in the internet but all have failed. I think we have to wait till developers find vulnerability in this de

Comment: @Risingmoon Still no Options?